# MySQL: Trigger in Table1 Inserts New Records Into Table 2. Can Trigger in Table 2 Then Update That Record in Table 1?

Tags: mysql, triggers

There are two tables :

1. tblapplicants
2. tbleligibility

Both tables share a common field. I'm trying to perform a 'roundabout' triggering (not an infinite loop).

1. The first table has an After_Insert Trigger that inserts its new records into the second table.
2. The second table then has a Before_Insert Trigger that performs a simple calculation.
3. I want to use this trigger of the second table to update that new record in the first table. Problem is when I add a new record into the first table, I keep getting *Error 1442: Can't update table 'tblapplicants' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger*.

I know I can use just one table to hold all the relevant fields; Project requires that two tables should be used.

For simplicity, only the triggers are posted here.

**Trigger of 1st Table**

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `add2tbleligibility` AFTER INSERT ON `tblapplicants` FOR EACH ROW 
  
BEGIN

INSERT INTO
     tbleligibility (ApplicantTableID, ApplicantName, DoB)
    VALUES (new.ApplicantID, new.ApplicantName, new.DoB);
END
```

**Trigger of 2nd Table**

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `checkeligibility` BEFORE INSERT ON `tbleligibility` FOR EACH ROW 
  
BEGIN

  SET new.AgeInDays = DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), new.DoB);

If DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), new.DoB) < 10950
THEN
SET new.Eligibility = 'Applicant is ineligible.';

UPDATE `tblapplicants`
SET `Eligibility` = 'Applicant is ineligible.'
WHERE ApplicantID = new.ApplicantTableID;

END IF;
END
```

Is what I am trying to do possible? I have also tried to use an After_Insert Trigger for the second table just to update the relevant record in the first table. It didn't work.

The full schema is in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ox_Q4tRI)

**UPDATE**
I tried using a Stored Procedure just for the Update of the first table as @Akina suggested. It was called from the After_Insert Trigger of the second table. It didn't work. I'm still getting the Error 1442.

The SP is below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test3`()

BEGIN

UPDATE `tblapplicants`
SET `Eligibility` = 'Applicant is ineligible.'
ORDER BY ApplicantID DESC LIMIT 1;

END
```

Comment: *Is what I am trying to do possible?* No. MySQL does not distinguish the action and time of a trigger - it simply tries to detect potential cycle presence, and forbids the trigger creation if it creates such cycle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the triggers were created. It's the execution that causes the error 1442. Alternatively, is there any other way to accomplish my objective without using a trigger?

Comment: You may use stored procedure instead of single INSERT. In this SP you may implement any logic which you need in.

Comment: @Akina I have tried using a Stored Procedure. I'm still getting Error 1442. See the update above. I am calling the SP from another trigger of the second table. Or is there another way to automate the running of the SP?

Comment: If table1 updates table2, which then needs to update table1, you have a bad design flaw in your database schema.

Comment: Put the `Eligibility` field in the second table and use a join when you need it with the first table.